# Selecting from multiple lists in model and putting it in a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to populate my dropdownlist by doing this

```
  var componentList = (from c in model.Components
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     compID = c.ID,
                                     compName = c.CompID + ":" + c.ComponentName
                                 }).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();
                      (from sc in model.ComponentSubComps
                                select new
                                {
                                     compID = sc.ID,
                                     compName = sc.SubCompID + ":" + sc.SubCompName
                                }).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

  ViewBag.Components = new SelectList(componentList, "compID", "compName");
```

But it is only pulling the data from the `model.Components` list in the model. How can I make it so it also pulls from the `model.ComponentSubComps` list as well?

Comment: Why would you need that much information anyway when building a select list, which can only take a key and a value?

Comment: Because there are different components in the component list and the subcomponent list @DavidLiang

Comment: so you wanna combine the component and subcomponent list and create a select list of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two statements. The result from the first statement you store in `componentList` but the result from the second statement isn't stored anywhere.

Try to **add** the **result** **from** the **second statemen**t to `componentList`.

Probably `List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` is the best option.

Edit:

```
var componentList = (from c in model.Components
                             select new
                             {
                                 compID = c.ID,
                                 compName = c.CompID + ":" + c.ComponentName
                             }).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

var secondResult = (from sc in model.ComponentSubComps
                            select new
                            {
                                 compID = sc.ID,
                                 compName = sc.SubCompID + ":" + sc.SubCompName
                            }).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

componentList.AddRange(secondResult);

ViewBag.Components = new SelectList(componentList, "compID", "compName");
```

Comment: How do I add two lists together?

Comment: store the result from the second statement in another variable (e.g. secondStatementResult). Then `componentList.AddRange(secondStatementResult)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to combine the components and sub-components or not. Combining them as a dangerous potential to mix up the IDs, assuming if they're in a separate table in your database and their primary keys are just incremental integer values.

This would become a serious bug if it's not being taken care of first. If their IDs could be the same, you might have to go with two dropdowns (one for components and one for sub-components) instead of one.

If you have to combine both of them, it sounds like you almost have to combine something uniquely with the IDs, assign them as different groups and parse the IDs when you receive from post back:

```cs
// Define the Groups
var componentGroup = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Component" };
var subComponentGroup = new SelectListGroup { Name = "SubComponent" };

var componentOptions = model.Components
    .OrderBy(x => x.ComponentName)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "c:" + x.CompID,
        Text = x.CompID + ":" + x.ComponentName,
        Group = componentGroup 
    });

var subComponentOptions = model.ComponentSubComps
    .OrderBy(x => x.SubCompName)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "sc:" + x.SubCompID,
        Text = x.SubCompID + ":" + x.SubCompName,
        Group = subComponentGroup
    });

var dropdownOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
dropdownOptions.AddRange(componentOptions);
dropdownOptions.AddRange(subComponentOptions);
```

Then when the user makes a selection and post the dropdown value back to the sever, you might have to parse the selected dropdown value and see if the ID belongs to component or sub-component.

If there is no difference between components and sub-components, then you can just combine them as easily as:

```cs
var componentOptions = model.Components
    .OrderBy(x => x.ComponentName)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.CompID,
        Text = x.CompID + ":" + x.ComponentName
    });

var subComponentOptions = model.ComponentSubComps
    .OrderBy(x => x.SubCompName)
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.SubCompID,
        Text = x.SubCompID + ":" + x.SubCompName
    });

// This is your SelectList. I would highly recommend you build a strongly-typed
// view model and use it instead of ViewBag.
var dropdownOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();
dropdownOptions.AddRange(componentOptions);
dropdownOptions.AddRange(subComponentOptions);
```

Comment: theres no difference between components and sub components. They are just lists in my model. For example a component can have 'sub-components' but really it's just that a component has components. Kinda confusing to explain. But I understand what you might've had concerns about

Answer (score 0):

You can write the queries with entities and get:

```
var componentList = model.Components.Select(c => new Components
{
    compID = c.ID,
    compName = c.CompID + ":" + c.ComponentName
}).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

var componentList1 = model.ComponentSubComps.Select(c => new Components
{
    compID = c.ID,
    compName = c.SubCompID + ":" + c.SubCompName
}).OrderBy(x => x.compName).ToList();

componentList.AddRange(componentList1);
ViewBag.Components = new SelectList(componentList, "compID", "compName");
```